# App restoration on Macbook Pro - will these apps be reinstalled whenever Big Sur launches?

Tags: macos, imovie, garageband

Before I delete iMovie and GarageBand on a shared MacBook Pro (I'm the admin), if I upgrade from MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 to Big Sur (whenever it launches), will they auto-restore on Big Sur being installed?

I know that if I want to reinstall I can do so via App Store, this question is more about the workings of Mac OS X.

[If I remove GarageBand and iMovie from my MacBook Air, can I restore them later?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101825/if-i-remove-garageband-and-imovie-from-my-macbook-air-can-i-restore-them-later) was the question I saw which related to this.

My question is not about *should* I delete them, but whether these will be automatically re-installed anyway on upgrade from new OS (I'm not talking incremental, e.g. from 10.15.7 to 10.15.8, but to a completely new OS).

Comment: We have had no issues reinstalling Apple apps to Big Sur in prerelease testing but until it’s out, Apple can and may make changes to the next OS.

Answer (score 1):

- I would expect automatic installs of apps like Garage Band and iMovie not happening when Big Sur is released.
- I would plan on these being easy reinstalls from the App Store.

The iLife and iWork apps are not part of the OS. Apple pre-installs them when you buy a new Mac which can lead people to assume they are part of the OS.  You need to download them again from the App Store if you wipe a machine and only install macOS.

This has been how it works for every release leading up to Big Sur so unless Apple makes a late change, count on signing in to the App Store to download any apps you don’t migrate from a previous backup.

Answer (score 1):

Because I use Logic Pro, I have no need of Garageband and it is not on my disks. I have updated my OS several times (Mojave, Catalina, Big Sur) and Garageband has not been reinstalled by the OS.